# Check if two strings are permutation of each other

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm solving a puzzle that needs to check if two strings are permutation of each other in O(N) with O(1) Space.

So my idea is to concatenate the two strings, and xor the result if its zero then it's a permutation.

But it fails in just one test case

```
Input1: pro
Input2: pro
 Pass
Input1: firecode
Input2: firecoat
Pass
Input1: firecode
Input2: codefire
Pass
Input1: abcd
Input2: cadb
Pass
Input1: GOD
Input2: DOG
Pass
Input1: [Empty]
Input2: [Empty]
Pass
Input1: firecode
Input2: firec
Pass
Input1: bbbb
Input2: dddd
 Fail
```

and here is my implementation:

```
bool permutation(string input1, string input2)
{

  string conct = input1+input2;


  int result = 0;

  for (int i =0; i < conct.size(); i++)
  {
      result^=conct[i];
  }

  return result ==0;
}
```

Comment: See https://www.fluentcpp.com/2019/06/25/understanding-the-implementation-of-stdis_permutation/ where there is an in-depth analysis of the corresponding algorithm of the STL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A classic O(n) solution with O(1) extra space that is good for data where the possible values are few is to build a table of occurrences and count how many times each element occurs. For the case of strings, it's quite easy:

```
bool permutation(string input1, string input2) {
    int count[UCHAR_MAX+1] = {};
    for(unsigned char c: input1) count[c]++;
    for(unsigned char c: input2) count[c]--;
    for(int x: count) {
        if(x) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Notice that I read each character in an `unsigned char`, as plain `char`'s signedness is implementation defined, and you don't really want to index my array with negative values.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [std::is_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_permutation).

```
bool permutation(const string &input1, const string &input2)
{
    return std::is_permutation(
        input1.begin(), input1.end(),
        input2.begin(), input2.end());
}
```

Comment: The point of the puzzle is to not use standard library, I know that function, what is the point then of using it ?

Comment: @AhmedSaleh Your question did not mention that. It should have.

Comment: `std::is_permutation` is O(n²), which is against OP's constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a logical error in your solution approach.

What you want to check is if the two strings have the same letters in them, which have the same number of occurences.

In your approach, what you are checking is if the concatinated string has an even number of occurences for each letter.

If you input "Hell" and "Helloo" you will find that your approach results in 0, even though these strings are not permutations of another.

Looking at the ASCII Binary table you can also construct things like "AB" and "C@", which will result in 0 as result:

```
A      0100 0001
B      0100 0010 ^= 0000 0011
C      0100 0011 ^= 0100 0000
@      0100 0000 ^= 0000 0000

result 0000 0000
```

*EDIT: corrected explanation, Added another example*

Comment: The question assumes both string are of the same length

Comment: Okay but you will get a false positive if you use "AB" and "C@" as the two strings even though they are of the same length.

Comment: Another simple example: Reducing XOR over any string in which every character is paired gives you 0. So this algorithm will happily report `aabb`, `ccdd`, `effe`, etc. as being permutations of each other.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Map data structure here and find the frequency of each element in both strings. If for any character's frequency differs means false.

Comment: A map is a generally appropriate compromise, trading space for time. In the question, though, time is the controlling constraint. So, an array is a better data structure in this case.